# haproxy stick table entry length

Tags: haproxy, sticky-sessions

I'm using `string` stick table:

- not specifying entry length (default 32 characters for `len` is exactly what i need)
- there is a note for `store` keyword stating: ***"For each
  item specified here, the size of each entry will be inflated so
  that the additional data can fit."***, so I was thinking the 32B are dedicate for my `stick on` entry,
- I use `server_id,server_key` in `store` and have accidentally realized, that `haproxy` stores only 31 characters for the stick key,
- re-reading the documentation again, I have found another (seemingly contradictory) note: ***"Several data types may be stored with an entry."***

1. Could this be the case the `server_id` and `server_key` consume the missing byte from the entry? I need to resize the entry by explicitly using the `len` and would like not to oversize it (seems like changing these parameters clears the table completely, which is a bit pity).
2. Any chance there is a list of items possibly stored in the entry space?
3. Any other explanation of the "cut" to 31B?

Using tables defined as follows:

```
table tbl-sticky-test type string size 1k srvkey name store server_id,server_key
```